# Design question: Polling on process in java spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, polling

I have a java / spring boot question about designing an app I have in mind.

The functional flow is this:
FE calls endpoint 'start process x' -> response ok/process (id?)
FE polls until status 'finished' endpoint 'get process status' -> response % progression
FE calls endpoint 'post process' -> post process result, response result

If endpoint 'start process x' is called again while one is already processing, it should queu that process and start processing after first one is finished.(Or better, allow max number of processes to run at same time, queuing the remainder)

How would I do this?
Do I need to start new threads, completable features?
How do I create a poll endpoint that can retrieve a status about this process?
How to create a queu?

I would love to have some examples, maybe an open repository where I can see a working example.